# probar libreria de redes neuronales

Tags: javascript, nodejs, redes-neuronales

Estuve probando la libreria https://github.com/cazala/synaptic, este es mi codigo

```
var synaptic = require('synaptic'); // this line is not needed in the browser
var A = synaptic.Neuron();
var B = synaptic.Neuron();
A.project(B);
A.activate(0.5); // 0.5
B.activate(); // 0.3244554645
```

lo copie del git

pero me dice

> Cannot read property 'project' of undefined

lo instale asi: npm install synaptic --save

y asi es mi arbol de mi proyecto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te has olvidado de usar `new`.

```
var A = new synaptic.Neuron();
var B = new synaptic.Neuron();
```

Fíjate en la [documentación](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Neurons).

Comment: que chorrada pero mas abajo lo inicializa solo asi: `var Neuron = synaptic.Neuron`,  creo que tiene muchas fallas esta lib,

Comment: @rn3w No.. ahi esta creando un ALIAS para luego hacer solo `var A  = new Neuron()`.

Comment: no se si estoy usando bien la lib mira este codigo del git `var A = new synaptic.Layer(5);
var B = new synaptic.Layer(3);
A.project(B);

A.activate([1,0,1,0,1]); // [1,0,1,0,1]
console.log(B.activate());` su res deberia ser // [0.3280457, 0.83243247, 0.5320423], pero sale // [ 0.4736686315236319, 0.48927028231620256, 0.47523251877050027 ]

Comment: @rn3w es el mismo valor, edita el comentario

Comment: lo edite, disculpas, puedes probarlo ? cada ves va cambiando la salida, ahora sale [ 0.5240200720664381, 0.4746627499632228, 0.46506710003768886 ] y ahora [ 0.5145755495883039, 0.5199883658355515, 0.48057686287113244 ]

Comment: @rn3w lo he mirado pero, la verdad que no te puedo ayudar casi nada con eso pues ni conozco la librería y de R-N se bastante poco. Lo siento, me gustaria poder ayudarte pero no puedo. Quiza puedas meter una pregunta de GitHub el la parte de Issues para entender como o porque no pasa lo que esperas que pase.